# Write RDD in txt file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following type of data:

```
  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String),Int)]] = MapPartitionsRDD[29] at map at <console>:38`
```

I'd like to write those data in a txt file to have something like

```
((like,chicken),2) ((like,dog),3) etc.
```

I store the data in a variable called `res`

But for the moment I tried with this:

```
res.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("newfile.txt")
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Go to your working directory and run `ls`

Comment: Please give more details - what does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Do you see exceptions? (if so - paste them). What/where did you check?

Comment: No sorry, actually my problem is that I don't have a txt file, with that command I only have " part-0000" and "part-0000.crc" as an empty file.
And what I want is a txt file with what I have in my RDD variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption is correct, then you feel that the output should be a single .txt file if it was `coalesce`d down to one worker. This is not how Spark is built. It is meant for distributed work and should not be attempted to be shoe-horned into a form where the output is not distributed. You should use a more generic command line tool for that.

All that said, you should see a folder named `newfile.txt` which contains data files with your expected output.